# Numbering sorted dates based Upon certain other row criteria

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count every time that a certain value within a row happens throughout an entire table, as one can see I've already sorted the table based upon date.

```
Campaign|Start Date|Phone Number
--------+----------+------------
A.      |09/01/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/02/2018|777-454-3333
A.      |09/03/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/04/2018|777-454-3333
A.      |09/05/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/06/2018|777-454-3333
A.      |09/07/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/08/2017|777-454-3333
```

Desired Output

```
Campaign|Start Date|Phone Number|Number of Occurrences within date
--------+----------+------------+---------------------------------
A.      |09/01/2018|555-444-3321|1
A.      |09/02/2018|777-454-3333|1
A.      |09/03/2018|555-444-3321|2
A.      |09/04/2018|777-454-3333|2
A.      |09/05/2018|555-444-3321|3
A.      |09/06/2018|777-454-3333|3
A.      |09/07/2018|555-444-3321|4
A.      |09/08/2017|777-454-3333|4
A.      |09/08/2017|999-432-1111|1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to calculate a row number for every distinct occurrence of phone number. If you have version 8 or above you can use row_number function. If not you can use variables as below.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(Campaign varchar(2), StartDate date,PhoneNumber varchar(20));
insert into t values
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/01/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'555-444-3321'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/02/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'777-454-3333'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/03/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'555-444-3321'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/04/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'777-454-3333'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/05/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'555-444-3321'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'777-454-3333'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/07/2018','%m/%d/%Y'),'555-444-3321'),
('A.'      ,STR_TO_DATE('09/08/2017','%m/%d/%Y'),'777-454-3333');

select *
from
(
select t.* ,
        if(phonenumber <>  @p, @occ:= 1,@occ :=@occ + 1) occurance,
        @p:=phonenumber  p
from t
cross join (select @occ:=0, @p:='') o
order by phonenumber,startdate
) s
order by startdate;
```

It's not clear from your question whether a phonenumber can occur more than once on a date or what want to happen if it does. Also your dates appear to be stored as text rather than date.